# Scala compilation error with Java parametrized constructor and parametrized interface

Tags: java, scala, javafx, javafx-2

When trying to compile the following code with Scala 2.8.1/JavaFx 2.0 beta

```
new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty, random() * height)
```

I get the following error:

```
[error]  found   : javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty
[error]  required: javafx.beans.value.WritableValue[Any]
[error]             new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty, random() * height)
[error]                                 ^
[error] one error found
```

Whereas this line gets compiled just fine:

```
new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty.asInstanceOf[WritableValue[Any]], random() * width)
```

I checked the *KeyValue* constructor and it has the following signature:

```
public <T> KeyValue(javafx.beans.value.WritableValue<T> tWritableValue, T t) { /* compiled code */ }
```

*circle.translateXProperty* returns *DoubleProperty* which implements the following interface:

```
public interface WritableNumberValue extends javafx.beans.value.WritableValue<java.lang.Number>
```

What would be more elegant solution than casting to make it compile?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the type? `new KeyValue[Any](circle...)`

Comment: Yep, I tried this but it says _KeyValue does not take type parameters_ (class _KeyValue_ is not parametrized, only constructor is)

Comment: Also I don't think that would change anything - from the error message you can see that the compiled has already inferred `Any` as the bound for `T`.

Comment: I am glad to know someone is already experimenting with coupling JavaFX 2.0 to Scala. I love Scala language and hope it will finally get a rich presentation platform as JavaFX 2.0 is released...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-- *Revised answer, based on Exception and Blaisorblade's comments* --

You've hit a limitation of Scala's application of implicits, rather than (just) a Scala-Java interop problem. Here's a simplified example,

```
class Foo[T]
def f[T](x: Foo[T], y: T): T = y

f(new Foo[Number], new java.lang.Double(0)) // OK; infers T==Number
f[Number](new Foo[Number], 0)               // OK; uses implicit int2Integer(0)
// f(new Foo[Number], 0)                    // error
```

- The first call to `f` works because the common supertype of `java.lang.Double` and `java.lang.Number` is `java.lang.Number`, so that is the type inferred for `T`.
- The second call to `f` works because we've explicitly told the compiler that `T==java.lang.Number`. When the compiler finds the second argument, `0 : Int`, doesn't match the expected type `java.lang.Number`, it searches for an implicit conversion from `Int` to `Number`. The compiler finds `Predef.int2Integer` and applies it. All is well.
- The third call to `f` doesn't work, because the first parameter constrains `T == Number`, and the second argument says `T >: Int` (that is, `T` is a supertype of `Int`). The common supertype of `Int` and `Number` is `Any`, but that won't work because `Foo[T]` is not covariant in `T` (in other words, we can't cast a `Foo[Number]` to a `Foo[Any]`). That's the gist of the compiler's error message. Note that the compiler doesn't know how to apply an implicit conversion, because it doesn't know a specific type of `T` to convert to.

One strange thing about the JavaFX code that you posted is that the [`KeyValue` class](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html) is not generic, but is has a generic constructor. Interestingly, this is *not* possible in Scala, so there's no way (as far as I can tell), to explicitly constrain the parameter `T` from Scala code. If the entire `KeyValue` class were generic, you'd also be able to write

```
new KeyValue[Number](circle.translateYProperty, random() * height)
```

which would be equivalent to the code that Exception posted, since the compiler would infer the `double2Double` conversion.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable!

Comment: I rewrote my answer since my original one was misleading.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem a few days ago. After trying different things i ended up with that.

```
new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty, double2Double(random() * height))
```

(see Blaisorblade comments for explanation)

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote the solution, but not the explanation. I believe that the problem is probably related to type inference - the type parameter T is inferred to be Any (as shown by the error messages), thus there is no need to apply an implicit conversion there, so the conversion is not applied.

Comment: Thats a good point and i may should point out that its just an assumption. I still try to figure out what causes the problem. But i wonder why it works if you give it a java.lang.Double if it has something to do with T being inferred as Any

Comment: One problem is that the common supertype for java.lang.Number and scala.Double is Any - if you change the latter to java.lang.Double, the common supertype is java.lang.Number. Not sure why Any is inferred though, unless WritableValue is considered to be covariant (but I think it is not, given the errors).

Comment: Ok this sounds plausible. Seems like i need to learn a lot more about generics to understand complex stuff like this. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. The compilation did work. Java Generics are funny :)